# Why do these methods compile to assembly?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

```
public class Inline {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long upto = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        for(int i = 0; i < upto; i++) {
            int x = inline1();
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    }
    public static int inline1() {
        return inline2();
    }
    public static int inline2() {
        return inline3();
    }
    public static int inline3() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

This is a simple example I am using to see the effect of safepoints and counter decay on methods being compiled to assembly.

My understanding is that with a `Thread.sleep` (or `System.gc`) call, the method invocation / back-edge counter would be decremented and would never reach over the `CompileThreshold`.

`Thread.sleep()` should insert a safepoint and the methods shouldn't be compiled. However when I run the example above with `-XX:+PrintCompilation`, I can see all the methods being compiled.

I am running the code as follows:

```
java -XX:+PrintCompilation Inline 10000
```

My Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *"the effect of safepoints and counter decay"*, and why you think that *"Thread.sleep() should insert a safepoint and the methods shouldn't be compiled."*.  A link to a reference that gives some background would help ....

Comment: @StephenC I am following [this guide](http://jpbempel.blogspot.in/2013/04/compilethreshold-is-relative.html) and reading Java Performance by Scott Oaks :)

Comment: the article you are reading is about just-in-time compiler which is different to running `javac` so a statement "this code doesn't compile" is not true

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I am invoking `java <classname>`. The code _does_ compile to bytecodes (class file) but I am unsure as to why it is being compiled from byte codes to assembly :)

Comment: Computer (processor) cannot execute any code - it can execute only assembly. You compile Java code to Java bytecode so that is executed by Java Virtual Machine which then internally compiles Java bytecode into assembly. Have a look at the introduction to Java in Oracle Java tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I am referring to "compilation" in the sense of "tiered compilation". The JVM will start with interpreting the bytecodes and profile it. After a certain threshold (`CompileThreshold`), the JVM will perform an On-Stack Replacement and use the purely-compiled version of the code and never interpret again (unless a deoptimization is triggered for some reason).

Comment: The article you reference is from 2013, it shouldn't surprise you that the Hotspot implementation might have changed since that time..

Comment: It has ... I looked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, the information you link to in your comments is out of date.  The ["CompileThreshold is relative!"](http://jpbempel.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/compilethreshold-is-relative.html) article is dated 2013, and is describing a version of Java available at that time.

If you look at the Java 8 and Java 9 OpenJDK source code, you will see that the counter decay code that was described in the article is no longer there.   That would explain why you are not seeing the effect in Java 8.

(The place to look is "./jdk8u/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/safepoint.cpp" in the source tree.)

Comment: Where can I view the source code of OpenJDK online? I am looking at the [Mercurial repo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share) and trying to find the path you've mentioned and I can't seem to find it :)

Comment: I installed mercurial and fetched the OpenJDK tree to my hard-drive.  It is easier to search (find, grep) if you have a local copy.